# How to make the following typescript definition more strict?

Tags: typescript

I have the below typescript definitions

```
// Type definitions
export enum TableFilterType {
    MULTIPLE = 'multiple',
    SINGLE = 'single'
  }
  
  export type TableBasePrimaryFilter = {
    type: TableFilterType;
    id: string | number;
    label: string;
    plural: string;
    icon?: string;
    unit?: string;
    iconClass?: Array<string>;
    optionsListWidth?: number;
  };
  
  export enum FilterDataLoadOrigin {
    CLIENT = 'CLIENT',
    SERVER = 'SERVER',
  }
  
  type TablePrimaryFilterCommon = {
    id: string | number;
    label: string;
    plural: string;
    type: TableFilterType;
  };
  
  export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilterClient = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
    mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT;
  };
  
  export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilterServer = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
    mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.SERVER;
    hasMore: boolean;
    total: number;
  };
  
  export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilter = TableMultiplePrimaryFilterClient | TableMultiplePrimaryFilterServer;
  
  export type TableSinglePrimaryFilterClient = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
    mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT;
  };
  
  export type TableSinglePrimaryFilterServer = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
    mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.SERVER;
    hasMore: boolean;
    total: number;
  };
  
  export type TableSinglePrimaryFilter = TableSinglePrimaryFilterClient | TableSinglePrimaryFilterServer;
  
  export type TablePrimaryFilter =
    | TableMultiplePrimaryFilter
    | TableSinglePrimaryFilter
```

Now the following should give an error (because when mode is client, hasMore and total should not be valid props) but it doesn't

```
  // Example
  const x: TablePrimaryFilter = {
    id: 'level',
    label: 'label',
    plural: 'plural',
    type: TableFilterType.SINGLE,
    mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT,
    // NOTE: The below lines should throw an error as hasMore and total should be invalid when mode is FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT
    hasMore: true,
    total: 100,
  };
```

How should I re-define my types to make it more strict?

I have tried different combinations of unions but nothing gives me the desired result

**Edit**
Adding a new filter type breaks the strictness

```
export enum TableFilterType {
  MULTIPLE = 'multiple',
  SINGLE = 'single',
  NUMBER = 'number',
}

export type TableNumberPrimaryFilter = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
  type: TableFilterType.NUMBER
};

export type TablePrimaryFilter =
  | TableMultiplePrimaryFilter
  | TableSinglePrimaryFilter
  | TableNumberPrimaryFilter
```

The following example should throw error but it doesn't

```
// Example
const x: TablePrimaryFilter = {
  id: 'level',
  label: 'label',
  plural: 'plural',
  type: TableFilterType.NUMBER,
  // NOTE: The below lines should throw an error as mode should be invalid when type is FilterDataLoadOrigin.NUMBER
  mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.SERVER,
  hasMore: true,
  total: 100,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet seems wrong because you define `mode: TypeEnums.CLIENT` in both `TableSinglePrimaryFilterClient` and `TableSinglePrimaryFilterServer` when the latter should contain `mode: TypeEnums.SERVER`.

Changing this does yield the desired result.

```js
export enum TableFilterType {
  MULTIPLE = 'multiple',
  SINGLE = 'single'
}

export type TableBasePrimaryFilter = {
  type: TableFilterType;
  id: string | number;
  label: string;
  plural: string;
  icon?: string;
  unit?: string;
  iconClass?: Array<string>;
  optionsListWidth?: number;
};

export enum FilterDataLoadOrigin {
  CLIENT = 'CLIENT',
  SERVER = 'SERVER',
}

type TablePrimaryFilterCommon = {
  id: string | number;
  label: string;
  plural: string;
  type: TableFilterType;
};

export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilterClient = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
  mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT;
};

export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilterServer = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
  mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.SERVER;
  hasMore: boolean;
  total: number;
};

export type TableMultiplePrimaryFilter = TableMultiplePrimaryFilterClient | TableMultiplePrimaryFilterServer;

export type TableSinglePrimaryFilterClient = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
  mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.CLIENT;
};

export type TableSinglePrimaryFilterServer = TablePrimaryFilterCommon & {
  mode: FilterDataLoadOrigin.SERVER;
  hasMore: boolean;
  total: number;
};

export type TableSinglePrimaryFilter = TableSinglePrimaryFilterClient | TableSinglePrimaryFilterServer;

export type TablePrimaryFilter =
  | TableMultiplePrimaryFilter
  | TableSinglePrimaryFilter
```

Comment: Sry my bad, have fixed that
But when I add new filter type, the strictness breaks.
I have edited the code please check it